# Как правильно оформить код в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 кнопки, каждая отвечает за срабатывание своей части контента, подскажите как это компактно оформить, чтобы не копировать одно и тоже изменяя число в переменной?

```
$('.button-a').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('.content-pic').lazy({     
   });
});

$('.button-b').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('.content-vid').lazy({          
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function connectButton(i) {
  $('.button-' + i).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.content-' + i).lazy({     
    });
  });
}

connectButton(1);
connectButton(2);
```

*Update*

```
function connectButton(buttonClass, contentClass) {
  $("." + buttonClass).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("." + contentClass).lazy({     
    });
  });
}

connectButton("button-a", "content-pic");
connectButton("button-b", "content-vid");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за готовый ответ, я немного неправильно описал проблему, что можно сделать если меняется не цифра в переменной, а слово?

Comment: @DannyWalker, а какая принципиальная разница между цифрой и словом?

Comment: @DannyWalker по вашему обновлённому вопросу можно просто два аргумента в connectButton передавать

Comment: Да, разницы никакой, хотел узнать для общего развития, большое спасибо! :)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте функцию, наверное может быть, а вообще да функцию. Типа функция будет принимать один параметр это ваше число Х. Все.

Comment: Молодец, Люба! Прямо в точку!